# American trade Hong Kong financial markets (specifically index options)

Tags: united-states, stocks, options, liquidity, hong-kong

How can an American get access to the Hang Seng index and index options? This trades in Hong Kong, but really exposure to Hang Seng stocks and derivatives (and index options) in general would be good.

**I am not looking for ETFs on US exchanges as they are not liquid enough and also trade during the wrong hours.**

I checked Interactive Brokers and they only have access to Hang Seng stocks. Underlying asset alone don't give me the flexibility to manage risk that I am accustomed to.

Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got your information about IB.

**Futures and Options list**
https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/trading/exchanges.php?exch=hkfe

**Mini Hang Seng Index Futures**
http://www1.interactivebrokers.ch/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?action=Details&site=GEN&conid=172256042

**Mini Hang Seng Index Options**
http://www1.interactivebrokers.ch/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?action=Details&site=GEN&conid=172474294